# how to make __COUNTER__ to generate the same value across different cpp files

Tags: c++, templates

I am using the [predefined `__COUNTER__` macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros) to define my type. However, if I access the variable `sval1` from main.cpp, it gets a different `__COUNTER__` value than if I access it from test.cpp.

How do I ensure that the same value for `__COUNTER__` is generated across all .cpp files?

```
template <class TYPE, DWORD CRYPT_KEY> 
class SVar;

struct t_teststruct
{
    SVar<type, __COUNTER__> sval1;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This seems like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why don't you just replace it with 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to include a header file (.h) in each source file (.cpp) that needs to access that variable. The header file should declare counter as an `extern`.

#### counter.h:

```
#ifndef COUNTER_H
#define COUNTER_H
  extern int __COUNTER__;
#endif
```

A single source file should contain the actual declaration of the variable (as well as any desired initialization).

#### counter.cpp:

```
#include "counter.h"
int __COUNTER__ = 0;
```

#### main.cpp:

```
#include "counter.h"

int main() {
    // etc.
    return 0;
}
```

#### test.cpp:

```
#include "counter.h"

struct t_teststruct
{
    SVar<type, __COUNTER__> sval1;
}

// etc.
```

Each source file should be compiled individually. Then the final executable can be linked against the `counter` object file:

```
g++ -o test.exe main.o test.o counter.o
```

Comment: That will make me use it as a global variable.

Comment: I need it to be a preprocessor "__COUNTER__"

Comment: Oh, well if you know it when you need to compile you could define it as a flag: `g++ -D__COUNTER__=5 ...`.

Comment: @user3575889 uh... what please?

Comment: No, i dont know it before compile time.

Comment: @AustinMullins He's talking about the [predefined `__COUNTER__` macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros). It gets automatically incremented on each usage within a translation unit. This whole thing smells of an X-Y problem.

Comment: Oooohhhhhh. I might need to delete this answer then. Totally misunderstood the question.

Comment: @AustinMullins You and me both.

Comment: and you can't use non-const variable in template arguments

Comment: I mis-write my question about the pre-processor so i will mark this answer as answer as it does answer the question, thanks.